# Not able to record Video while scanning using Google Vision API

Tags: android, google-vision

I am using Google Vision API to scan Bar-codes and it is working fine. So now while scanning bar-codes, I want to record a video of scanned bar-codes.

To achieve it, I am using MediaRecorder to record the video. But when the recording starts, scanning is failing. I am assuming this is because of unlocking the camera to record the video.

Is there any way to record a video while scanning using Google Vision API.

TIA